Why were the Germans accused of genocide at the start of WW1 against the Belgium people?
My understanding is that Belgium refused the Germans unchallenged passage through Belgium and into France as a precursor move at the very start of WW1. This, ostensibly, angered the  Germans to commit atrocities against the civilian population. Is this true, or is it disinformation spread by the British?

Why do you think it was "disinformation spread by the British"?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s) Citations ?  Source for "my understanding"?  In the absence of any evidence that Germany was accused of genocide, I'd recommend closure.

Presumably to rally the British public into backing going to war.

Whatever may have been wartime propaganda, you might want to read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_of_Belgium and maybe https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_of_Death

Interesting Wikipedia article. Especially the enumeration of contributory factors, unbelieveable that such attrocities could be inflicted on a previously neutral country.

from the point of view of the german the neutrality of belgium was "scrap of paper" (as cited in the wikipedia article), so from their point of view that matters nothing.
specially from that point of view, we can see the atrocities caused by fear of Franc-tireurs rather than the unchallenged passage

@DanM: I's important to note the origin of the German reasoning behind that statement - namely that it was exactly what Napoleon told Prussia after France violated the neutrality of Prussian Ansbach and Bayreuth during the Ulm campaign. Certainly Germany was a tad obtuse perhaps - but the precedent had been firmly set and accepted. The Germans were totally unready for a Belgian partisan effort matching Tyrol's 1809 rebellion in ferocity and determination.

@IronDuke Please edit all your comments into the question.

Germany was not formally accused of genocide against the Belgian people during ww1. Instead, what occurred was a series of brutal actions known as the Rape of Belgium, which involved severe war crimes committed by German forces against Belgian civilians during the invasion and occupation of Belgium from 1914 to 1918.
These actions included mass killings and the destruction of civilian property. The atrocities aimed to suppress resistance and maintain control over occupied territories through fear and intimidation rather than to exterminate the Belgian people, which distinguishes these acts from genocide.

Excellent, thank you.

In retrospect, what should the Albert I have done that could have saved his people from such atrocities? Total capitulation? Perhaps this was unrealistic given the partisans operating unilaterally within the country?

Rules of war are developed by negotiation among nations, and sometimes by the result of negotiation becoming accepted standards which are binding even those nations which did not sign up explicitly. The rules of war then have to be translated into rules of engagement, and those rules must then be enforced by the military.
The German forces had concerns about a repeat of francs-tireurs of the war of 1870/72, whom they considered what would be called unlawful combatants or terrorists one and a half centuries later. Their plan to prevent it included Schrecklichkeit, demonstrative harshness to intimidate the population. This played into German theories of war as an effort of the entire society, not just the uniformed forces, and the need to secure the rear areas with limited forces while most troops were used in a battle of encirclement.
So German troops were predisposed to see guerilla action in the fog of war, and to suppress it harshly. German conduct violated the 'civilized' norms which were supposed to apply in Western and Central Europe. It was an era of double standards; what was acceptable in colonial wars was not acceptable in the homelands of colonial powers.
Similar issues were to come up when the rules of cruiser warfare ran into the technological realities of submarine warfare.

One and a half centuries? Did you mean 35 years?

@Spencer, I meant that Germans planned to treat Belgian civilians suspected of carrying arms much as many Western countries treated suspected terrorists one or two decades ago. I'll edit to clarify the issue of double standards.
